# Change the border of matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to change a zero matrix of size n x n into a matrix that has 1's in the border.

I first initialized zero matrix by doing

```
zm = np.zeros((n, n))
```

tried

```
zm[:1] = 1
```

to change the first row to 1, but I am having a trouble changing the rest.